Unable to Install Platform Dependent Package using Environment Marker
I am using hatchling as python package build system
The problem:

I have 2 different python packages (both are written by me) named foo and bar
foo is platform dependent package and should only be installed in Windows platforms
bar is platform independent package and should be installed on any Windows and/or UNIX platforms
bar uses foo for some of it's sub-packages

I am trying to add foo as a dependency of bar using an environment marker which should only be installed on Windows platforms.
foo's pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "foo"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name="John Doe", email="John.Doe@example.com" },
]
description = "FOO"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
dependencies = [
    "pywin32"
]
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows"
]

bar's pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "bar"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name="John Doe", email="John.Doe@example.com" },
]
description = "BAR"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
dependencies = [
    "foo @ file:///C:/Users/bkm/Workspace/temp/foo; platform_system == 'Windows'"
]
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent"
]

[tool.hatch.metadata]
allow-direct-references = true

When I am trying to install bar on a Windows platform, I am getting the following error:
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/bkm/Workspace/temp/bar
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\bkm\Workspace\temp\bar\winenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\bkm\Workspace\temp\bar\winenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bkm\Workspace\temp\bar\winenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 176, in prepare_metadata_for_build_editable
          whl_basename = build_hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bkm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rz8bsp6f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\build.py", line 83, in build_editable
          return os.path.basename(next(builder.build(directory=wheel_directory, versions=['editable'])))
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bkm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rz8bsp6f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\plugin\interface.py", line 90, in build
          self.metadata.validate_fields()
        File "C:\Users\bkm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rz8bsp6f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\metadata\core.py", line 266, in validate_fields
          self.core.validate_fields()
        File "C:\Users\bkm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rz8bsp6f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\metadata\core.py", line 1376, in validate_fields
          getattr(self, attribute)
        File "C:\Users\bkm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rz8bsp6f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\metadata\core.py", line 1230, in dependencies
          self._dependencies = list(self.dependencies_complex)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bkm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rz8bsp6f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\metadata\core.py", line 1208, in dependencies_complex
          raise ValueError(message) from None
      ValueError: Dependency #1 of field `project.dependencies` is invalid: Expected end or semicolon (after URL and whitespace)
          foo @ file:///C:/Users/bkm/Workspace/temp/foo; platform_system == 'Windows'
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.1.2 -> 24.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip


It happens to be a silly space ( ) issue.
Here is my updated pyproject.toml for bar
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "bar"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name="John Doe", email="John.Doe@example.com" },
]
description = "BAR"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
dependencies = [
    "foo @ file:///C:/Users/bkm/Workspace/temp/foo ; platform_system == 'Windows'"
]
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent"
]

[tool.hatch.metadata]
allow-direct-references = true

